# How to perform api versioning in .net core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I've written a controller like below (.net core 2.1):

```
[ApiVersion("1")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: api/Account
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

I'm calling the above controller in this way (swagger call):

```
curl -X GET "https://localhost:44363/v1/Account" -H "accept: application/json"
```

But I keep getting a 404 error like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /v1/Account</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong.  Any help is highly appreciated !

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? What is your `Startup.cs`? I fail to reproduce your issue iwth current settings.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to provide the route like that, as it already is known by api versioning system.

First of all, you should configure api versioning, for example:

```
public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddApiVersioning(o => o.ApiVersionReader = new HeaderApiVersionReader("api-version"));

    //and the rest
}
```

And then simple configuration:

```
services.AddApiVersioning(
    o =>
    {
        o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true );
        o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion( 1 );
    } );
```

This will create default api version and assume that if no version is specified in request, default one will be taken under consideration.

Next your controller should look like that:

```
[ApiVersion( "1" )]
[Route( "api/mystuff" )]
public class mystuff1: Controller 
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get() => "Mystuff1!";
}


[ApiVersion( "2" )]
[Route( "api/mystuff" )]
public class mystuff2 : Controller 
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get() => "Mystuff2!";
}
```

Then just add header to your request:
api-version: 2

(this is done by AddApiVersioning in ConfigureServices).

Comment: sorry, it didnt work.  Still gives me 404 error :(  Has something changed in 2.1 as compared to 2.0 ?

Comment: Are you sure that you have api version in your header when sending request? Are you sure, you have correct naming? For example "api-version" instead of: "api-verson"?